# Table CSS has different effects in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm trying to get columns in a table to have a predefined height, and to scroll to allow their content to fit. What I have currently works in Chrome and Safari, but not on Firefox (at least on my MacBook). In Firefox, the table's height grows to fit all its contents for some reason.

Here is the HTML,

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="scrolling_div">
                ...{content}...
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

the css,

```
/*** css reset ***/
html * { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; font-size: 1em; text-decoration: none; line-height: 1em; }
ol, ul { list-style: none; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }

/*** actual css ***/
table {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vh;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.scrolling_div {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

and the [JSFiddle for this question](https://jsfiddle.net/0acegbam/3/).

This can be fixed if you set the height of .scrolling_div to a specific number of pixels, but I'd like to keep it at 100% to make it fill the table, so this works for different table sizes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add 'max-height:tableHeight' to .scolling_div

```
.scrolling_div {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 50vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers handle things like styling differently. Chrome and Safari are both WebKit browsers so its understandable they're achieving similar results.

You can target specific browsers by referencing their vendor prefixes.

Let's say you wanted a table `border-radius` of `50%` on Chrome and Safari, but Firefox is adding more padding by default, so you'd like to tone it down for that browser alone, to `45%`:

```
table {
  border-radius: 50% // non-specified browsers will fallback to this
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%; // safari and chrome
  -moz-border-radius: 45%; // firefox
}
```

Here is a list of a bunch of vendor extensions for webkit:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Webkit_Extensions

I'm not sure what exactly is causing your issue - but if you're getting different behaviour amongst browsers, vendor prefixes are the best way to start with debugging.